# CSS and JS files not loading after moving WordPress site to new server

Tags: wordpress, ssl, apache2, centos7

**BACKGROUND**

I had a WordPress website on IIS on a Windows Server. It was a dedicated server and very expensive, so I moved to a CentOS VPS with Vultr.

I have installed new versions of PHP, MariaDb and Apache2. Created a VirtualHost file for my website, and issued an SSL Cert with Let's Encrypt through Certbox.

**ISSUES**

[My website](https://www.nativeleaf.co.uk) is up and running, but none of the CSS and JS files are being loaded and I've no idea why. This obviously creates a mess on my website as everything looks ugly is not working.

[image: errors]

I'm getting a `net::ERR_ABORTED`

Also, the certificate isn't showing the green-tick in chrome, not sure why that is either.

What have I missed?

Comment: I think it's js and css Compress issue, Please uninstall the bwp-minify plugin and check.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have done the trick but looks like I've got theme issues too. I'll ask the theme authors for support on that. Thanks.